# how to Dynamically add custom row in ListView in android

Tags: android

Calling Adapter list (`AdaptorMessageList`) will show the two list. What I want to do is when I do something like clicking the button, it should add one new custom row dynamically

```
                        String[] name = {"hello","how "};
                        String[] address = {"mustang","josmoms"};
                        int[] img = {R.drawable.b,R.drawable.b};
                    AdaptorMessageList adaptor = new AdaptorMessageList(getContext(),name,address,img);
                    messageListView.setAdapter(adaptor);
    
    
    
                 }
            });
        }
    
         class AdaptorMessageList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
                Context context;
                String[] profile_name;
                String[] profile_hometown;
                int[] profile_picture;
                AdaptorMessageList(Context c,String[] profile_name,String[] profile_hometown,int[] profile_picture){
                    super(c,R.layout.single_row_comm_user_list,R.id.profile_name,profile_name);
                    context=c;
                    this.profile_name = profile_name;
                    this.profile_hometown = profile_hometown;
                    this.profile_picture = profile_picture;
                }
        
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_comm_user_list,parent,false);
                    TextView Tprofile_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
                    TextView Tprofile_hometown = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.profile_hometown);
                    ImageView Tprofile_picture = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
                    Tprofile_name.setText(profile_name[position]);
                    Tprofile_hometown.setText(profile_hometown[position]);
                    Tprofile_picture.setImageResource(profile_picture[position]);
                    return row;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add data in adapter on ItemView click and notify change using notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: Thank you for respond but Would you please tell me more clearly , i didn't get it...

Answer (score 0):

Just add items to `String[]` arrays `name` and `address` which you have linked to adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`